# Handle quickbook receive payment transaction event before add payment in quickbook using quickbook SDK

Tags: quickbooks

I have used below code to attach quckboook events

```
// Subscribe to UI events...
            InformManager.SubscribeToQBUIEvents(handleUIEvents);

            // Subscribe to data events...
            InformManager.SubscribeToQBDataEvents(handleDataEvents);
```

& this code works when we save any receive payment in quickbook QB dataevents called.

currently i m getting list id & txn type of receive payment which i added. but i want event before add receive payment

```
public void handleDataEvents(object sender, DataEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.QBEvent.OREvent.DataEventList.Count > 0)
            {
                string OperationString = args.QBEvent.OREvent.DataEventList.GetAt(0).ORListTxnEvent.TxnEvent.TxnEventOperation.GetAsString();
                string OperationType = args.QBEvent.OREvent.DataEventList.GetAt(0).ORListTxnEvent.TxnEvent.TxnEventType.GetAsString();
                if (OperationType == "ReceivePayment" && (OperationString == "Modify" || OperationString == "Add"))
                {
                    ProcessPaymentClick(args);
                }
            }
        }
```

**but i want to event before receive payment add in quickbook.** 
pls suggest..

Comment: Hi Sai Sherlekar, I need help importing Quick book's data using  QuickBook SDK. Can you please look at this link .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455576/how-to-import-quick-books-data-in-to-our-own-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no QuickBooks SDK event that fires before the payment is received. You're already doing everything you can to capture the payment.

Comment: i m creating a plugin same as QBPOS addon.
means any user will create receive payment entry in quickbook & on save we will show popup to make payment but if user declines that popup then payment entry should not be created.
how can i achieve this pls suggest...

Comment: QBPOS is more flexible that the QBSDK. In QuickBooks it is not possible to prevent the creation of the payment entry.